# Extract the metric measurable in the product title

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My Objective is to extract the metric measurable in the product title.

Example: I have the following products with their titles:

```
Product title A: "Milk 12KG 1Box"
Product title B: "Apple 10Plus 256GB"
Product title C: "Samsung 4G 3S"
```

After spitting product title by white-space, I have this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [np.array(['Milk', '12KG', '1Box'],dtype=object),np.array(['Apple', '10Plus', '256GB'],dtype=object),np.array(['Samsung', '4G', '3S'],dtype=object)]


for arr1 in arr:
    sum_list = []
    for a in arr1:  
        sum = 0
        for i in range(10):
            sum += a.count(str(i))
        sum_list.append(sum)
    print(arr1,"->",sum_list)
```

Output:

```
['Milk' '12KG' '1Box'] -> [0, 2, 1]
['Apple' '10Plus' '256GB'] -> [0, 2, 3]
['Samsung' '4G' '3S'] -> [0, 1, 1]
```

Desired Output:

1. Item containing more numbers than other items.
2. In case there are more than 1 item containing same amount of numbers, take the item having bigger length.
3. In case there are more than 1 item containing same amount of numbers and having the same length, take the item having the first order.

```
['12KG']
['256GB']
['4G']
```

How to get desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'[^\d]+'
>>> for item in arr:
...     idx = np.argmax(np.array([len(re.sub(pattern, '', x)) for x in item]))
...     print(item[idx])
...

12KG
256GB
4G
```

**EDIT**

For your updated requirement

```
>>> arr
[array(['Milk', '12KG', '1Box', '#123'], dtype=object), array(['Apple', '10Plus', '256GB'], dtype=object), array(['Samsung', '4G', '3S'], dtype=object)]
```

---

```py
>>> pattern = r'^#.*|[^\d]+'
>>> for item in arr:
...     idx = np.argmax(np.array([len(re.sub(pattern, '', x)) for x in item]))
...     print(item[idx])
...
12KG
256GB
4G
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting NameError: name 'pattern' is not defined. Kindly let me know more. I did import re

Comment: Hi abhilb, just a follow up. In case I have noise in product title like ['Milk', '12KG', '1Box',"#123"], the code above is taking "#123" instead of "12KG". Let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: `Item containing more numbers than other items` is the requirement isn't?

Comment: Maybe not, the final objective is to get the product metric out of the product title. If we have noise in the product like #123, the code above is not understanding. Thanks

Comment: how do you define noisy data? anything that starts with #?

Comment: Yes, my full product title is "Milk 12KG 1Box #123". After splitting by whilespace I get ['Milk', '12KG', '1Box',"#123"]. I think the code will need to ignore anything with #. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I advise you not to mix types in `a` in order to make all the calculations `numpy` - based only. You can convert `a` into a tidy form by a command:

`a = np.array(a).astype(str)`

And after that we calculate result as follows:

```
# array of matrices that represents amounts of symbols for each word:
symbol_counts = np.array([np.char.count(a, symbol) for symbol in '0123456789']) 
# element-wise addition of these matrices:
total_counts = np.sum(symbol_counts, axis=0) 
# indices of word that has the most digits in each row:
idx = np.argmax(total_counts, axis=1)
# corresponding words:
result = np.choose(idx, a.T)
print(result)
```

#### Output:

```
['12KG' '256GB' '4G']
```